# Jquery PHP Mysql Form Submit not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

This is so stressfull for a beginner..
i want make simple chat, user send message to database without refresh page.
**Why this is not working (*I have used this before and it's working*) ..?**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


 $(function () {

        $('#formnya').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'chat_save.php',
            data: $('#text_nya').serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success: function () {
                $('#text_nya').val('');
            }
          });

        });

      });
</script>
```

form is :

```
<form method="post" action="" id="formnya">
<input class="w3-input w3-border-3 w3-white" placeholder="Click to chatting...." name="message" type="text" id="text_nya" maxlength="70"/>
<input name="submit" class="w3-btn w3-black" type="submit" value="Send" id="submit" />
</form>
```

the php :

```
if (isset($_POST['message'])) {


        $message=$_POST['message'];
        query("INSERT INTO {{pick}} sender='MyUsername', message='$message', time=now()","chat");

}
```

Comment: Are you getting any JS or PHP errors ?

Comment: If you don't intend for the default form action to submit, you should change your input type from submit to button.

Comment: I love all the comments about what you should do that are completely unrelated to your question. These must be master programmers. As for your question, Arvin, I'm not seeing anything wrong with your methodology. If I had to guess at the issue, it would be your function `query()`. Would you add that to the question, so that we could help your further?

Comment: Any console messages? Do you get a '200 OK' for the ajax call? Also check what is sent. Then you should be really careful if you sending the chat message into the database without escaping it?

Comment: I can see $('#text_nya').serialize(), in ajax function but your form has <form method="post" action="" id="formnya">

Comment: Thanks guys for fast answer...when form submitted, its success (you can see #text_nya value "". but my database chat is not receieve any data.

Comment: Could you show us the body of your `query()` function ?

Comment: function query($query, $pick) { 
  
    include('connect_database.php');
 $dbsettings["prefix"] = "wetable";
    $doingquery = mysql_query(str_replace("{{pick}}", $dbsettings["prefix"] . "_" . $pick, $query)) or die(mysql_error());
    return $doingquery;

}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use $message with double quotes instead of single quotes ? This would be like that :

```
query("INSERT INTO {{pick}} sender='MyUsername', message=".$message.", time=now()","chat");
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've try your method too, but its not working :(

Comment: i've found the problem i guess, when i change            success: function (data) { then alert(data), it show this problem: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'sender='MyUsername', message='aaa', time=now()' at line 1. How to solve this?, i see everything is ok here.

Answer (score 0):

In index.php, add the code below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>AJAX </title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

jQuery(function () {
    jQuery('#formnya').on('submit', function (e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: 'chat_save.php',
            data: jQuery('#text_nya').serialize(),
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(result);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>


</head>
<body>

<form method="post" action="" id="formnya">
<input class="w3-input w3-border-3 w3-white" placeholder="Click to chatting...." name="message" type="text" id="text_nya" maxlength="70"/>
<input name="submit" class="w3-btn w3-black" type="submit" value="Send" id="submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

and in chatsave.php, add the code below:

```
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['message'])) {

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "stackoverflow";
    //echo $message = $_POST['message'];

    // Create connection
    $conn =  mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    mysqli_select_db($conn, $dbname);
    $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['message'] );
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 

    $sql = "INSERT INTO pick (sender, message, m_time)
    VALUES ('MyUsername', '$message', now())";

    mysqli_query($conn , $sql);

    if ($sql == TRUE) {
        echo "New record created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
    }
}
```

Tested locally. Worked like a charm at my localhost.

Comment: Trying this, but not working for me. Btw, thanks for your comment.

Comment: Can you share your complete code because i am on localhost it's working at my side. without any error. Or you can inspect element.

Comment: Thanks bro for your help. The problem is solved. I'm so idiot that didnot see there's no "set" when inserting data. -> Insert into tabel SET xxxx